# Excel Add-in for custom ribbon tab to include controls from MSIP.ExcelAddin

Tags: excel-addins, ribbonx

I'm trying to build an Excel add-in too distribute a company specific tab for the Ribbon.

In the ribbon I want to include the Sensitivity-control from office365 Sensitivity app (MSIP.ExcelAddin). It seems like this come both as a regular MS add-in, with mso-controls, and as a 3rd party add-in, with x1-controls.

I can successfully build and distribute a custom ribbon using the built in Ribbon-customizer, *.exportedUI file, I can user either the group or the control from of the 3rd party add-in.
The MSO-version doesn't works, that is also the case in the original Home-tab.

```
<mso:cmd app="Excel" dt="0"/>
<mso:customUI xmlns:x1="MSIP.ExcelAddin" xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <mso:ribbon>
        <mso:tabs>
            <mso:tab id="mso_c1.CD9101F" label="3rd Party Tab" insertBeforeQ="mso:TabInsert">
                <mso:group idQ="x1:adxRibbonGroup_f46a9e941d544d01ad8b43917c503243"/>
                <mso:group id="mso_c2.CD9101F" label="My Group" autoScale="true">
                    <mso:control idQ="x1:adxRibbonMenu_b0e02808fb2f409f90503955cef756aa" visible="true"/>
                </mso:group>
            </mso:tab>
            <mso:tab id="mso_c3.CD96023" label="MSO Tab" insertBeforeQ="mso:TabInsert">
                <mso:group idQ="mso:GroupClassifyLabelProtect"/>
                <mso:group id="mso_c4.CD96033" label="My Group" autoScale="true">
                    <mso:control idQ="mso:ClassifyLabelProtect" visible="true"/>
                </mso:group>
            </mso:tab>          
        </mso:tabs>
    </mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
```

However, when doing the same in my add-in project i can't get it to work.

```
<customUI xmlns:x1="MSIP.ExcelAddin" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="mso_c1.CD9101F" label="3rd Party Tab" insertBeforeMso="TabInsert">
                <group idQ="x1:adxRibbonGroup_f46a9e941d544d01ad8b43917c503243"/>
                <group id="mso_c2.CD9101F" label="My Group" autoScale="true">
                    <control idQ="x1:adxRibbonMenu_b0e02808fb2f409f90503955cef756aa" visible="true"/>
                </group>
            </tab>
            <tab id="mso_c3.CD96023" label="MSO Tab" insertBeforeMso="TabInsert">
                <group idMso="GroupClassifyLabelProtect"/>
                <group id="mso_c4.CD96033" label="My Group" autoScale="true">
                    <control idMso="ClassifyLabelProtect" visible="true"/>
                </group>
            </tab>  
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

In the first Tab, holding the 3rd Party Controls I get an empty tab.
The second Tab shows only the single and inactive control in My Group.

Do I do something wrong when defining or referencing the namespace for the 3rd party add-in?

Answer (score 0):

You can place your custom ribbon UI into a custom tab or group by specifying the namespace.  The key is specifying the same unique namespace in the `<customUI>` tag. Then, controls can reference this namespace by using `idQ`. The `idQ` property of controls exists to enable multiple add-ins to share containers, such as custom tabs and groups, but not placing custom controls from other add-ins into yours.

BTW Do you get any UI errors in the Office application?

By default, if an add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear. Read more about that in the [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2019) article.

Comment: Thanks, I don't get any UI errors, I haven't configured that yet, will try.
I start to understand referencing another add-in's control will not be possible.
However adding another add-in's Group, to my Tab should be possible.
So how can i determine the name space for this MSIP.ExcelAddin?
BTW is that the x1-part or MSIP.ExcelAddin-part?

Comment: I enable UI errors, I can confirm that it works, as I found an error in another add-in.
When I fixed that I got no more errors.
In my custom ribbon I try to add the groups from MSIP. They don't show and there are no errors. I added both the MSO-version and the idQ-version.

Comment: When adding the control (idQ-version) as a control I get an error saying I can't att custom controls as <control>. So I tried using <menu>, i now have something in the ribbon, but not the control I expected. What type of control can this be? An button which expands to a menu.

Comment: It seems this is a topic for another thread, right?

Comment: What do you mean, by other topic?
The the topic is how to get the MSIP controls in my own Custom Ribbon.